# excel macro beforeclose event

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following macro to convert text to numbers for all the values.
Since linked server is loading the xls, the format got messed up.
Columns are already formatted e.g, accounting, percentage, number....etc, but even though
everything are saved as text.

So I decided to run the macro before closiong the workbook.
The macros goes like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Cells.Select
  Range("D1").Activate
  Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 1).Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
  With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = False
  End With
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "test.xls"
  ActiveWorkbook.Close 
End Sub
```

But the thing is, it pops up window to ask if I wanna save the changes,
How can I fix that.

Above macro takes little longer to execute!!!

I have fixed columns(till D1) but valiable rows.

Can somebody help me to figure this out.

Comment: `I have fixed columns(till D1) but valiable rows.` I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: That means I wanted to convert all text to numbers and my range is from A1 to D1.I have fixed number of columns but can have any numbner of rows

Comment: I'm going to update my answer, but the short answer is you need to use the `CDec()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the thing is, it pops up window to
>   ask if I wanna save the changes, How
>   can I fix that.

Add in `ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True` after `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "test.xls"`.  There are a few other options [here](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/22/closing-a-workbook-without-a-prompt/)(involving suppressing the alerts, but that could affect any other open workbooks, too).

Select whatever column you want:

```
Sub ConvertToText()
   Dim xCell As Range
   Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Select 'does the first column
   For Each xCell In Selection
     xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
   Next xCell
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that but I am getting : Run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error at this line: Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) _
    .Offset(1, 1).Copy

Comment: @user234194 What are you trying to do with that line?  I think that method should be run for the `ActiveRange` object instead of `Cells`, but with the offset, you're taking the cell at a diagonal from the current one.

Comment: Could you please help me modify the above macro as I am new on that.

Comment: @user234194 Yes, see my other comment.

Comment: Ok...But I dont know whether it gonna work for all the comumns, after running above macro, all the formats on different cells becomes activated, i.e they produce defined cell format. If Cdec() does the same then I will. I havent worked much in Macros and I am also NOT a VB guy... so I wanna do minimal changes. Thanks

Comment: @user234194 Updated answer, you can adopt it by setting whatever range you need to instead of just the first column

Comment: I modified the range to Range("A5:D5").End(xlDown).Select and could not make it work...

Comment: @user234194 Use something like `Range("A5:D" & Range("D5").End(xlDown).Rows).Select`